# react-native clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build my react-native project in Xcode to release in App Store but the build fails with the error

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I have facebook sdk and react-native-firebase in my project. Can you please help me what could be wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This error mostly occur when node modules aren't correctly installed in the react-native-ios. Better check if the pods are installed correctly or the .xcodeproj are included and correctly linked with project.

```
react-native link
```

react-native link doesn't correctly link all the packages. So recheck it and it manually or using cocoapods.

If further information from the pod are shared, I can help you to find the correct module.

Comment: platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myapp' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.11.0'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
end

Comment: Above is my pod file contents. Thanks Krishnaraj!

Comment: I have the same error but with project initialized with react-native-cli and latest version of react native 0.71 or 0.72 , react native link does not work as it is not required.  Linking part is said to be automatically taken care of. How can I solve this with the latest version of xcode and react native @Krishnaraj

Comment: that's right changes have been made based on latest react native. react-native link is no linger required @catBuddy

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this error by doing some changes in Xcode app info.

1. Open Xcode in application
2. Right click and open on **Get info**
3. you will find three option there, check on **Open using Rosetta**.
4. Now close the Xcode completely, and then open.
   Now you are able to make build successfully.