# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 ( yarn ios : build failure )

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, cross-platform

React native project is initialized with react-native-cli and version 0.71 for react native.
I run commands:

```
pod deintegrate --> success
pod setup --> success
pod install --> success
yarn ios --> build fails
```

I see the following error

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-proj
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

command

> react-native link

does not work as it is not required.  Linking part is said to be automatically taken care of in latest versions of react native. I see same question asked in the past for older versions and solution 1 points to the use of above command.But, it is not solution for latest react native .

Here is the link for solutions tried

[solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193022/react-native-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1#:%7E:text=This%20error%20mostly%20occur%20when,and%20correctly%20linked%20with%20project.&text=react%2Dnative%20link%20doesn%27t%20correctly%20link%20all%20the%20packages.) and [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619799/xcode-10-beta-5-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1/53103383#53103383)

I  need help to resolve this with the latest version of xcode and react native.

**Note:** that a blank new project with react native cli runs successfully. But this is an existing android project that I am trying to run on ios